# Django won't run migrations. TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, django

I get `TypeError: expected string or buffer` when I try to run migrations in my Django project. It occurs if I add a `DateField` into a existing model `creation = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)`.

The only way I can get around it is to startup a new project and copy and past the code from the old to the new. I have tried deleting the migrations, deleting the database and deleting the code that coursed the problem in the first place.

How is it that the error can still pop up after all that has been removed and more importantly, how do I stop it happening on a live database.

Traceback

```
Applying apps.0011_auto_20150928_1515...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Name/pyProjects/projects/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Name/pyProjects/projects/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/Name/pyProjects/projects/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/Name/pyProjects/projects/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/Name/pyProjects/projects/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 222, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/Name/pyProjects/projects/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/Name/pyProjects/projects/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 148, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/Name/pyProjects/projects/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/Name/pyProjects/projects/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/Users/Name/pyProjects/projects/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 179, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "/Users/Name/pyProjects/projects/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 77, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(field)
  File "/Users/Name/pyProjects/projects/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 211, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/Users/Name/pyProjects/projects/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 710, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/Users/Name/pyProjects/projects/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1322, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Users/Name/pyProjects/projects/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1317, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/Users/Name/pyProjects/projects/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1274, in to_python
    parsed = parse_date(value)
  File "/Users/Name/pyProjects/projects/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 60, in parse_date
    match = date_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: Please show the full error and traceback.

Comment: I have added that thanks

Comment: Could you post your model too!?

Comment: Could you please also write whate Django Version and what Database you are using?

Comment: It does not matter whats in my model. I could comment all the code out and I still get it.

Comment: sqlite3 and Django 1.8